# Ошибка в XMLLoader.load()

Tags: java, javafx

Начал недавно писать на `JavaFX`!
Задача такая: по нажатию кнопки на основном окне, должно вызываться дополнительное окно(Модальное окно)!

Модальное окно должно подгружать с `FXML`!

Вот класс:

```
public class OptionWindow {

    public void OptionWindow() throws IOException {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        AnchorPane pane = FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("option.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 400);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.setTitle("Настройка");
        window.showAndWait();
    }

}
```

Вот ошибка:

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: /C:/Users/BillSwon/IdeaProjects/TestforWork/out/production/TestforWork/sample/option.fxml

Подскажите в чем проблема? Пожалуйста!

Comment: по всей видимости в том, что Вы не можете загрузитьoption.fxml. Скорее всего у Вас путь к  криво прописан

Comment: + посмотри в сторону `javafx.scene.control.Dialig` вместо создания новой сцены

Comment: Ответ найден! Дело в том что я в scene bilder наделал ошибок ! Я написал все заново и все стало норм!